# Breakable tcolorbox and internallinenumbers

Tags: tcolorbox, line-numbering, lineno

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[3]
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
    \begin{internallinenumbers}
        \blindtext[2]
    \end{internallinenumbers}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

One will get this on the second page:

[image]

Is there any way to fix this behavior?

Comment: Have you ever fixed this?

Comment: @theV0ID No, and that's why I kept two separate implementations in my package "mindflow". The tcolorbox version is more customizable but line numbering inside breakable boxes has always been an issue.